# Meaning of "features protection has reached maximum number of loops" warning

Tags: cgal

I am using make_mesh_3() with protected features and sometimes get the following warning “features protection has reached maximum number of loops. It might result in a crash.cgal”. I would like to fix this issue but am not sure why I am getting this warning to begin with. What triggers this warning exactly?

Comment: My guess is that you have features that are very closed together and the feature protection algorithm cannot separate them. If you can provide a minimal example than can be compiled and run, you should submit an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues) to get a precise answer.